# How to do SSRS Document Map bookmarking for subreports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS solution with several subreports in one report. Client needs bookmark(in PDF) for each subreport as shown below.

[image]

Left section shows SSRS design page with textboxes and subreports stacked . Right side shows the result we need to achieve.

I tried the below link to set DocumentMap. But could find a solution how to apply this for subreports. 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3504/sql-server-reporting-services-bookmarks-and-document-maps/

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a map entry to point to your subreport then you can set this by simply clicking on the subreport from your main report and setting the DocumentMapLabel property

[image]

If you need your document map to point to specific parts of your subreport that requires a bit more effort but still pretty simple. You have to setup a document map within the subreport. This will then be nested in the main report's document map.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thanks for the tip.
I have done the DocumentMapLabel property for each Section header (textbox) and Sub header(textbox) and it is working. But the requirement is to put the Subheaders under the Section header (like a hierarchy or tree).

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with a collapsible group. You could get something similar by adding some spaces to the start of the document map to indent it but you won't get the `+/-` button. SSRS needs a hierarchical structure to produce the document map from, this would normally be a tablix with row groups. I can't think of another way of doing it